# Strange border showing up in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that I am writing and its for the most part still in mockup so there is not much c# behind it.

I'm noticing a strange 1px border or separator between two sections of my window that according to the XAML should not be there, nor is it there at design time, but at run sure enough I can't get rid of it. (annotated by red arrow)

[image]

Main windows XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DS4Windows" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" xmlns:Forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DS4Windows.MainWindow"
        Title="DS4Windows DSDCS Build" Height="519" Width="965" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="519">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Backgrounds/BlueBG2.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </Window.Effect>


    <DockPanel Margin="0">

        <DockPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </DockPanel.Background>
        <DockPanel x:Name="TopPanel" Height="92" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MouseDown="WindowDrag">
            <DockPanel.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </DockPanel.Background>
            <Image x:Name="ProgramIcon" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Icons/Icon.png" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
            <Menu x:Name="MainMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Opacity="0.9" FontSize="14">
                <MenuItem x:Name="FileMenu" Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Quit"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem x:Name="ToolsMenu" Header="Tools"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="HelpMenu" Header="Help"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="AccountMenu" Header="My Account" SubmenuClosed="AccountMenu_SubmenuClosed">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="UsernameMenuItem" Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenu}">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="Username" Width="76" Padding="0"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="UsernameInput" Width="134"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="PasswordMenuItem" Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenu}">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="Password" Width="76" Padding="0"/>
                                <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordInput" Width="134"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="LoginMenuStatus" Header=""  Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenu}" Foreground="#FF515151" FontSize="11" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="LoginButtonMenuItem" Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenu}">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" Click="LoginButton_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator x:Name="LoginMenuSeperator"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="RegisterAccountMenuItem" Header="Register account"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ForgotLoginMenuItem" Header="Forgot login"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="LogoutMenuItem" Header="Logout" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="LogoutMenuItem_Click"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Label x:Name="WindowTitle" Content="DS4Windows DSDCS Build (1.5 ALPHA)" Height="30" Margin="5,5,100,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="ExitMenu" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,-35,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.525,0.211" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="X" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,5,0" Background="#FFFF7878" FontWeight="Bold" Click="CloseButton_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,0.421" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="22" MouseEnter="CloseButton_MouseEnter"/>
                <Button x:Name="MinimizeCloseOpt" Content="Minimize to tray" Visibility="Hidden" Click="MinimizeCloseOpt_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="QuitCloseOpt" Content="Quit" Visibility="Hidden" Click="QuitCloseOpt_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="UsernameLabel" Content="Guest" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,-100,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="Footer" Height="28" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Source="Icons/ResizeGrip.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="WindowResize" Cursor="SizeNWSE">
                <Image.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Icons/ResizeGrip.png" Stretch="None"/>
                </Image.OpacityMask>
            </Image>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="AddPanel" Height="94" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Frame Content="Frame" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="728" Source="http://dsdcs.com/index.php?template=frontend" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="SidebarDockPanel" Background="#CCFFFFFF" Margin="0">
            <StackPanel Height="305" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
                <telerik:RadOutlookBarItem Header="Home" Icon="Icons/Home.ico" IsSelected="True" FontSize="14">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
                </telerik:RadOutlookBarItem>
                <telerik:RadOutlookBarItem Header="Macros" Icon="Icons/Macros.ico" Height="38" FontSize="14">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
                </telerik:RadOutlookBarItem>
                <telerik:RadOutlookBarItem Header="Log" Icon="Icons/Log.ico" Height="38" FontSize="14">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
                </telerik:RadOutlookBarItem>
                <telerik:RadOutlookBarItem Header="Settings" Icon="Icons/Settings.ico" Height="38" FontSize="14">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
                </telerik:RadOutlookBarItem>
            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="MainWinDockPanel" Background="#CCFFFFFF">
            <Expander x:Name="CurrentGameWindow" Header="Currently Playing: Nothing" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="#B2000000" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Panel.ZIndex="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                <DockPanel Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <Image x:Name="CurrentGameBoxart" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                        <Image.OpacityMask>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="TempImages/5647-1.jpg"/>
                        </Image.OpacityMask>
                    </Image>
                    <Grid x:Name="CurrentGameBGFrame" Margin="0">
                        <Image x:Name="CurrentGameRating" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="12,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
                        <Label x:Name="CurrentGamePublisher" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Label x:Name="CurrentGameDeveloper" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Label x:Name="CurrentGameGenres" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Label x:Name="CurrentGamePlayers" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="12"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </Expander>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                <Frame x:Name="MainNav" Content="Frame" Source="/DS4Windows;component/Pages/Home.xaml" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Child page XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="DS4Windows.Pages.Home"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Home" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ControllerStack" Margin="0">
        <StackPanel Height="69" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Icon1" Width="61" Source="/DS4Windows;component/ControllerStates/wireless-icon-48.png"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,0,0">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="BatteryMeter1" Height="20" Margin="0,18,0,0" Width="150">
                    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFF4C4C" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF830000" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
                </ProgressBar>
                <Label x:Name="ChargeStatus1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="69" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Icon2" Width="61" Source="/DS4Windows;component/ControllerStates/DS4_C_Gray-icon-48.png"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,0,0">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="BatteryMeter2" Height="20" Margin="0,18,0,0" Width="150">
                    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF37E03F" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1F9524" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
                </ProgressBar>
                <Label x:Name="ChargeStatus2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="69" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Icon3" Width="61" Source="/DS4Windows;component/ControllerStates/DS4_C_Gray-icon-48.png"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,0,0">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="BatteryMeter3" Height="20" Margin="0,18,0,0" Width="150">
                    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF37E03F" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1F9524" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
                </ProgressBar>
                <Label x:Name="ChargeStatus3" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="69" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Icon4" Width="61" Source="/DS4Windows;component/ControllerStates/DS4_C_Gray-icon-48.png"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,0,0">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="BatteryMeter4" Height="20" Margin="0,18,0,0" Width="150">
                    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF37E03F" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1F9524" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
                </ProgressBar>
                <Label x:Name="ChargeStatus4" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Your code will *not* replicate your problem... you try adding it to a new project and see what happens.

Comment: Is that a TabControl it's sitting in that I'm not seeing in your xaml? If so then yes there's a default BorderBrush in the default TabControl style template with a 1px border set to `<SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}"/>` you'll just need to go pull out or templatebind or something

Comment: @ChrisW. I assume the buttons on the left are what you are referring to? No im using Telerik buttons for those `<telerik:RadOutlookBarItem>` and the main page is just a frame.

Comment: Opening up the control template for the telerik control, I'm seeing a lot of things with a `BorderThickness` of 1 on them. Have you tried changing any of those?

Comment: Yea the buttons themselves have a border, but nothing that extends down below like that. When I set the dock panel that they are contained inside to a fixed width the line disappears.

Comment: Whoa wait, what? Just throwing a fixed width on the dockpanel makes it disappear?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately i want the side dockpanel to be auto so this is not a 'fix' just another symptom of whatever the issue is.

Comment: Heres a thought, maybe its the difference between how HW and SW handles floating point numbers and aliasing? what the line is is actually a gap between the controls showing up and the reason its only visible at runtime is because thats the only instance in which it is relying on the HW to paint the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, not an 100% answer to the question of why, but a fix; I added both the sidebar and main window dock panels to a new parent dockpanel control ans set the opaque background on that wrather the child controls. This got rid of the border which I suspect was actually a gap.

The why, at least I think; With all child and parent controls on the sidebar set to auto the width was being determined by calculating the width of the button string + image + padding. Since WPF is hardware rendered the width could have calculated it with aliasing considered and the response may have been a floating point number rather than an integer like if I manually set the width myself. so with a floating point width the aliasing of the two adjacent controls likely caused a fraction of a pixel width of background to show through, result in a 1px line or border as I thought it was. And since design time renders the control in SW mode this was never seen until the application was actually run.

Not sure if its taboo to answer my own ? but I figured I would for others sake who may come here with same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand why things in WPF looking odd or how they render you should take a look at [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Hint: If you want to jump to the current `Control` move the mouse over it and press `Shift` + `Ctrl`

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a "hint"

Comment: Totally true Chris, but the answer will be hard to give because we cannot really reproduce the problem. So I thought to recommend Snoop as a solution. :)